# How to format output using pandas and data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have huge file with 500k records (input) with similar pattern

input.txt:

```
p m a b
1 0 10 100
1 1 11 111
1 2 12 122
2 0 20 200
2 1 21 211
2 2 22 222
```

Can you please let me know, how to format this file as below

Output:

```
r, p, 0, 1, 2

a, 1, 10, 11, 12
a, 2, 20, 21, 22
b, 1, 100, 111, 122
b, 2, 200, 211, 222
```

tried below code but still unable to format the output:

```
df=pd.read_csv('input.txt',sep=' ')
print(df)

df_trans=df.transpose()
print(df_trans.iloc[:,0:3])

  0 1 2
p 1 1 1
m 0 1 2
a 10 11 12
b 100 111 122
```

Expected output header will have these entries
r, p, 0, 1, 2

```
r - new column need to be added (not part of input file)
p - it is part of input
m - value need be used in header (0, 1, 2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sharath.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.pivot(index=['p'], columns='m', values=['a', 'b']).stack(0).reset_index()
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'level_1': 'r'})
df2 = df2.sort_values(['r', 'p']).reset_index(drop=True)

m  p  r    0    1    2
0  1  a   10   11   12
1  2  a   20   21   22
2  1  b  100  111  122
3  2  b  200  211  222
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), as follows:

```
(df.set_index(['p', 'm'])
   .stack()
   .unstack(level=1)
   .reset_index(level=0)
   .rename_axis(index='r', columns=None)
   .reset_index()
   .sort_values('r', ignore_index=True)
)
```

or use [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), as follows:

```
(df.pivot(index='p', columns='m', values=['a', 'b'])
   .stack(level=0)
   .reset_index(level=0)
   .rename_axis(index='r', columns=None)
   .reset_index()
   .sort_values('r', ignore_index=True)
)
```

**Result:**

```
   r  p    0    1    2
0  a  1   10   11   12
1  a  2   20   21   22
2  b  1  100  111  122
3  b  2  200  211  222
```